# store return url of a FilePicker script

Tags: javascript, filepicker.io

so ive got the filepicker script in my site:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//api.filepicker.io/v1/filepicker.js"></script>

<input type="filepicker" data-fp-apikey="A9sWQqHKDSLu0QkEeY1qnz" data-fp-mimetypes="image/*" data-fp-container="modal" data-fp-multiple="true" data-fp-services="COMPUTER,FACEBOOK,INSTAGRAM" onchange="out='';for(var i=0;i<event.fpfiles.length;i++){out+=event.fpfiles[i].url;out+=' '};alert(out)">
```

Two questions to you masters:

a. How can I somehow store the image url that the file picker returns. the idea is to store it in a kind of "choose you're product" page, and implant that url later, on another web form.

b. How can I make a live preview of the image uploaded by my customer, in the same page of the uploading, just so they can verify that this is the right picture.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="//api.filepicker.io/v1/filepicker.js"></script>

<input type="filepicker" data-fp-apikey="A9sWQqHKDSLu0QkEeY1qnz" data-fp-mimetypes="image/*" data-fp-container="modal" data-fp-multiple="true" data-fp-services="COMPUTER,FACEBOOK,INSTAGRAM" onchange="out='';for(var i=0;i<event.fpfiles.length;i++){out+=event.fpfiles[i].url;out+=' '};alert(out)">

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jWyek/

It has some example code to show you how you can display the image.

Put in a placeholder image:

```
<img id="placeholder" src=""></img>
```

And then set the source url when you get it from filepicker

```
$('#placeholder').attr('src', url);
```

It also shows you the placeholder for where you could save the image for later.

```
//do what you need to store the url
```

I'm not sure what your system looks like and this part is going to be super specific to your code and setup.

Comment: Thank you Liyan Chang!
for saving the image, im noe sure my system (shopify ecommerce) can handle the storage, is it possible to write a script tahat will save the image from the url in dropbox or google drive?
the saving must happen only after the customer enters his details in a next page.

Comment: There is no need to store the file as the link will keep working. If you'd like a copy, I would suggest you set up an s3 bucket and integrate filepicker and it will put it in your bucket.